# Как удалить \n из строки Lua?

Tags: строки, lua

Как удалить символ переноса строки (`\n`) из строки в Lua?

У меня `whoami` выдает имя текущего пользователя с `\n` на конце...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Используйте `string.gsub`:

```
local whoami = "ABC\n"
print("'" .. whoami .. "'")
-- 'ABC
-- '
local res, _ = whoami:gsub("\n", "")
print("'" .. res .. "'")
-- 'ABC'
```

См. [демо онлайн](https://ideone.com/BYOWFq)

Если необходимо удалить пробельные символы в начале и конце строки, можно воспльзоваться шаблоном:

```
whoami:gsub("^%s*(.-)%s*$", "%1")
```

См. [ещё одно демо онлайн](https://ideone.com/h1d8Wk).

Тут

- `^` - начало строки
- `%s*` - 0+ пробельных символов
- `(.-)` - Захватывающая подмаска №1, которая находит 0 и более любых символов, как можно меньше
- `%s*` - 0+ пробельных символов
- `$` - конец строки.

`%1` в строке замены подставляет значение, сохранённое в буфере первой захватывающей подмаски.

Comment: спасибо, работает.

Comment: @Wiktor - так ты, оказывается, ещё и русский знаешь?

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff Егор, я вообще-то кандидат наук по специальности 10.02.04 (германские языки). В общем, да, русский :)

Comment: @Wiktor - а семейство языков регулярных выражений, наверное, тоже относится к группе германских языков? ;-)

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff Смешно. :) Регулярные выражения мне нужны по работе, мы используем их для проверки качества переводов. Все наши лингвистические правила основаны на регулярках.

Comment: @Wiktor - у вас там, видимо, регулярки по несколько килобайт каждое, по сравнению с которыми вот [это](http://www.ex-parrot.com/~pdw/Mail-RFC822-Address.html) выглядит слишком простым? ;-)

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff Большинство наших регулярок создаются автоматически с помощью скриптов. Они могут быть очень длинными и нечитабельными. А есть регулярки, написанные вручную, они гораздо короче. Вы к чему клоните? :)

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/70239/discussion-between-egor-skriptunoff-and-wiktor-stribizew).

Answer (score 1):

Для ситуации, когда надо удалить переводы строк в начале и конце строки:

```
whoami:match('^\n*(.-)^\n*$')
```

Тут

- `^` и `$` - начало и конец строки
- `\n*` - 0 и более символов перевода строки (если необходимо удалить любые пробельные символы, то заменить на `%s*`)
- `(.-)` - захват необходимых символов, не трогая "жадные" захваты